# Wavelets: how to determine scales from frequencies?

Tags: matlab, frequency, wavelet, wavelet-transform, time-frequency

In the following code sample, I would expect the rows of the printed output to match each other, at least approximately. But they don't.

```
% input data
y  = rand(10000,1); 
dt = 1/500; % 500Hz is the sampling rate


% wavelet transform
f  = 1:50;                    % frequencies at which to perform WT
s  = scal2frq(f,'morl',dt);   % corresponding scales estimates
wt = cwtft( y, 'wavelet', 'morl', 'scales', s );

[ f; wt.frequencies/dt ]
```

I am trying to use the continuous wavelet transform in Matlab, and I want to perform the transform at different *frequencies* in my input signal, but I am struggling to find a reliable way for estimating the corresponding *scales*.

In that code sample, I am using `scal2freq` to estimate those scales (knowing that it is involutory, ie that `scal2frq(scal2frq(x,'morl',dt),'morl',dt) == x` up to numerical precision for all `x, dt`), but then I would expect that the frequency estimates returned by `cwtft` would be similar. As you can see, they are not.

Does anyone know how `cwtft` estimates these frequencies, and whether I can use the reverse estimate to predict the required scales?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correspondence between frequency and scales for the Morlet wavelet is `scale = 6 / (2*pi * frequency*dt)` (where `frequency*dt` is in cycles/unit).